# Search with select box in a table with jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a list table:

```
<select name="time">
   <option value="">Select time</option>
   <option value="AM">AM</option>
   <option value="PM">PM</option>
</select>
<table id="delivery">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Time</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>A</td>
        <td>AM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>B</td>
         <td>PM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>C</td>
         <td>AM</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

And my script:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
   function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
      //filter on current position which is column 3            
      colFilterID = 3;

      //get our filter element
      filterElement = aData[colFilterID] * 1;

      //get our filter time from the SELECT drop down in header of column
      filterTime = $("select[name='time']").val();

      if(filterTime == '') {
         return true;
      }

      if(filterTime == filterElement ) {
         return true;
      }
});
$("select[name='time']").on('change', function() {
   oTable.fnDraw();
});

var table = $('#delivery');
var oTable = table.dataTable();
```

I'm unable to filter records by third column with `AM` and `PM` values.

Comment: Post a full code. or create a demo using jsfiddle. This piece of javascript code will through the undefined error for afnFiltering

Answer (score 0):

> **CAUSE**

There are couple issues with your code:

- column indexes are zero-based, so index of the third column is `2`
- you're trying to convert string to number with `aData[colFilterID] * 1` which turns string into `NaN`
- your code doesn't always return a value, you need to return `false` if the strings do not match.

> **SOLUTION**

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
   function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
      //filter on current position which is column 3 (zero-based index is 2)
      colFilterID = 2;

      //get our filter element
      filterElement = aData[colFilterID];

      //get our filter time from the SELECT drop down in header of column
      filterTime = $("select[name='time']").val();

      if(filterTime == '') {
         return true;
      }

      if(filterTime == filterElement) {
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;    
      }
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/um3o11L5/) for code and demonstration.